# Random non deterministic results from pretrained retinanet

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation, retinanet

I wrote the following class to perform instance segmentation and return the masks of a given class.
The code seems to be running randomly and it's not deterministic.
The labels printed (as well as the number of labels) change at every execution even if I am running the code on the same input image containing a single person.
Is there a problem in how I load the weights? The code is not printing any warning nor exception.
Note that I am running the code on the CPU.

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch import Tensor
from torchvision.models.detection import retinanet_resnet50_fpn_v2, RetinaNet_ResNet50_FPN_V2_Weights
import torchvision.transforms as T
import PIL
from PIL import Image


class RetinaNet:

    def __init__(self, weights: RetinaNet_ResNet50_FPN_V2_Weights = RetinaNet_ResNet50_FPN_V2_Weights.COCO_V1):
        # Load the pre-trained DeepLabV3 model
        self.weights = weights
        self.model = retinanet_resnet50_fpn_v2(
            pretrained=RetinaNet_ResNet50_FPN_V2_Weights
        )
        self.model.eval()
        # Check if a GPU is available and if not, use a CPU
        self.device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
        self.model.to(self.device)
        # Define the transformation
        self.transform = T.Compose([
            T.ToTensor(),
        ])

    def infer_on_image(self, image: PIL.Image.Image, label: str) -> Tensor:
        # Transform image
        input_tensor = self.transform(image)
        input_tensor = input_tensor.unsqueeze(0)
        input_tensor.to(self.device)
        # Run model
        with torch.no_grad():
            predictions = self.model(input_tensor)
        # Post-processing to create masks for requested label
        label_index = self.get_label_index(label)
        boxes = predictions[0]['boxes'][predictions[0]['labels'] == label_index]
        print('labels', predictions[0]['labels'])    # random output
        masks = torch.zeros((len(boxes), input_tensor.shape[1], input_tensor.shape[2]), dtype=torch.uint8)
        for i, box in enumerate(boxes.cpu().numpy()):
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, box)
            masks[i, y1:y2, x1:x2] = 1
        return masks

    def get_label_index(self,label: str) -> int:
        return self.weights.value.meta['categories'].index(label)

    def get_label(self, label_index: int) -> str:
        return self.weights.value.meta['categories'][label_index]

    @staticmethod
    def load_image(file_path: str) -> PIL.Image.Image:
        return Image.open(file_path).convert("RGB")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    image_path = 'person.jpg'
    # Run inference
    retinanet = RetinaNet()
    masks = retinanet.infer_on_image(
        image=retinanet.load_image(image_path),
        label='person'
    )
    # Plot image
    plt.imshow(retinanet.load_image(image_path))
    plt.show()
    # PLot mask
    for i, mask in enumerate(masks):
        mask = mask.unsqueeze(2)
        plt.title(f'mask {i}')
        plt.imshow(mask)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html) can help.

Comment: I get the exact same result each time running your code on my side. Could you try to update PyTorch to the last version?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I always implement the below script and reproduce exactly same result, except for using DDP.

At the start point of `__main__` script,

```
seed = 3407
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
# torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)  # raise error if CUDA >= 10.2
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
random.seed(seed) # import random
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
```

DDP dataloader samplers with asynchronous task reproduces the different data augmentation by time. It can be handled with some tricks, but not used on my way.

At the implementation of `dataloader` class,

```
g = torch.Generator()
g.manual_seed(seed) # the seed used in above
dataLoader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(generator=g)   # your dataloader
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I mean, shouldn't the same model give more or less the same results? I get your point. If you set the seed, you get reproducible results. But the problem here is that I have a pretrained model which seems to be giving completely random results

Comment: I just read my comment and I noticed it sounds rude. Sorry, I didn't mean to sound like that! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @user1315621
As mentioned in the main comment, the same results are reproduced in my env, both CPU and GPU. Try my suggestion, move the "model.eval()" right before the "with torch.no_grad()", and wrap the post process in the "with torch.no_grad()". Allocating memory depends on your env can make some errors.